# Create to talk about universities and programs

Tags: word-choice

Do you use "create" to talk about universities and programs?

"They have to create international programs for exploring space and create international universities connected with the space programs."

Comment: I would say that they were _set up_ or _established_ rather than _created_

Comment: I would avoid the repetition of the word "create", either by re-structuring the sentence, or as Kate suggests, by using an alternative word the second time. ("Create" is perfectly adequate for me.)

Answer (score 1):

Any phrase which would similar to "create" would suffice:

> They have to ***establish*** international programs
> They need to ***formulate*** international programs
> They need to ***originate*** international programs

and the appropriate synonym would depend on context.